# Minimal polynomial and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{F}),$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, and suppose that $m_A(t)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$. Let $w$ an eigenvector of $A$. Say $Aw = \lambda w.$ If $k$ is the degree of $m_A(t),$ then what is possible to say about $\dim \{v \mid Av = \lambda v \}?$

Obviously $k \le  n.$ I know that if $k = n,$ then $\dim \{v \mid Av = \lambda v \} = 1,$ but for $k < n,$ I have no idea how can I proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimension of the eigenspace $E_\lambda$ is known as the *geometric multiplicity* of the eigenvalue $\lambda$. It cannot exceed the *algebraic multiplicity* of this eigenvalue, i.e. its multiplicity as a root of the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(t)$.

A criterion  for  diagonalisability asserts that  $A$ is diagonalisable if and only if the geometric and algebraic multiplicities of each eigenvalue of $A$ are equal.  It is also that the minimal polynomial $m_A(t)$ has only simple roots.